# Hide & show multiple class elements with buttons in the menu

Tags: javascript, html, list, class, toggle

I know this has been asked multiple times, but none of the questions match my case in a way.

This is my timeline website: http://witch-house.com/thetimeline/

It uses this structure:

```
<ul>
<li class="blog"></li>
<li class="blog"></li>
<li class="artist"></li>
<li class="mix"></li>
<li class="blog"></li>
<li class="artist"></li>
.
.
.
</ul>
```

now, I want to have 4 clickable buttons on top of my website: 'SHOW ALL', 'ARTISTS', 'BLOGS', 'MIXES'

by default SHOW ALL option will be on and it will show all `<li>` elements

when you click ARTISTS, the website will only show all `<li>` elements tagged with `class="artist"` + change the ARTISTS button colour to red

when you click BLOGS on top of this, all `<li>` elements tagged with `class="blog"` will appear (next to previously clicked ARTISTS) + the button will change colour to red too

etc

when you click SHOW ALL button again, all elements should be visible and all other buttons should go back to standard colour.

I've found this "simple" solution:
https://isabelcastillo.com/toggle-showhide-multiple-elements-with-pure-javascript

but it targets only sibling elements, not all class elements:

**HTML**

```
<h2 class="clickable-heading">Toggle This Dropdown</h2>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">How To Do This</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Installing in The Mid 90s</a></li>
</ul>
<h2 class="clickable-heading">Click This Dropdown 2</h2>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Vote For Pedro</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Your Name is Napoleon?</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
function toggleDocs(event) {
    if (event.target && event.target.className == 'clickable-heading') {
        var next = event.target.nextElementSibling;
        if (next.style.display == "none") {
            next.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            next.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
document.addEventListener('click', toggleDocs, true);
```

is there a way to tweak it?

or maybe another suggesion how to tackle this?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

> **Using Pure Javascript**

```js
        document.querySelector('#showAll').onclick = function () {
            document.querySelector('#showAll').innerHTML = 'Show All';
            document.querySelector('#toggleBlog').innerHTML = 'Hide Blogs';
            document.querySelector('#toggleMixes').innerHTML = 'Hide Mixes';
            document.querySelector('#toggleArtists').innerHTML = 'Hide Artists';
            document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(function (item, i) {
                item.style.display = '';
            });
        };

        document.querySelector('#toggleBlog').onclick = function () {
            document.querySelectorAll('li.blog').forEach(function (item, i) {
                item.style.display = item.style.display == '' ? 'none' : '';
            });

            document.querySelector('#toggleBlog').innerHTML = document.querySelector('#toggleBlog').innerHTML == 'Hide Blogs' ? 'Show Blogs' : 'Hide Blogs';
            if (document.querySelector('#toggleBlog').innerHTML == 'Hide Blogs' && document.querySelector('#toggleArtists').innerHTML == 'Hide Artists' && document.querySelector('#toggleMixes').innerHTML == 'Hide Mixes')
                document.querySelector('#showAll').innerHTML = 'Show All';
            else
                document.querySelector('#showAll').innerHTML = 'Not All';
        };

        document.querySelector('#toggleArtists').onclick = function () {
            document.querySelectorAll('li.artist').forEach(function (item, i) {
                item.style.display = item.style.display == '' ? 'none' : '';
            });

            document.querySelector('#toggleArtists').innerHTML = document.querySelector('#toggleArtists').innerHTML == 'Hide Artists' ? 'Show Artists' : 'Hide Artists';
            if (document.querySelector('#toggleBlog').innerHTML == 'Hide Blogs' && document.querySelector('#toggleArtists').innerHTML == 'Hide Artists' && document.querySelector('#toggleMixes').innerHTML == 'Hide Mixes')
                document.querySelector('#showAll').innerHTML = 'Show All';
            else
                document.querySelector('#showAll').innerHTML = 'Not All';
        };

        document.querySelector('#toggleMixes').onclick = function () {
            document.querySelectorAll('li.mix').forEach(function (item, i) {
                item.style.display = item.style.display == '' ? 'none' : '';
            });

            document.querySelector('#toggleMixes').innerHTML = document.querySelector('#toggleMixes').innerHTML == 'Hide Mixes' ? 'Show Mixes' : 'Hide Mixes';
            if (document.querySelector('#toggleBlog').innerHTML == 'Hide Blogs' && document.querySelector('#toggleArtists').innerHTML == 'Hide Artists' && document.querySelector('#toggleMixes').innerHTML == 'Hide Mixes')
                document.querySelector('#showAll').innerHTML = 'Show All';
            else
                document.querySelector('#showAll').innerHTML = 'Not All';
        };
```

```html
<button id="showAll">Show All</button>
    <button id="toggleBlog">Hide Blogs</button>
    <button id="toggleArtists">Hide Artists</button>
    <button id="toggleMixes">Hide Mixes</button>

    <ul>
        <li class="blog">Blog 1</li>
        <li class="blog">Blog 2</li>
        <li class="artist">Artist 1</li>
        <li class="mix">MIX 1</li>
        <li class="blog">BLOG 3</li>
        <li class="artist">Artist 2</li>
    </ul>
```

> **Using jQuery**

```js
        $('#showAll').click(function () {
            $('#toggleBlog').html('Hide Blogs');
            $('#toggleMixes').html('Hide Mixes');
            $('#toggleArtists').html('Hide Artists');
            $('li').each(function () {
                $(this).show();
            });
        });

        $('#toggleBlog').click(function () {
            $('li.blog').each(function () {
                $(this).toggle();
            });
            $('#toggleBlog').html($('#toggleBlog').data('state') == 'shown' ? 'Hide Blogs' : 'Show Blogs');
        });

        $('#toggleArtists').click(function () {
            $('li.artist').each(function () {
                $(this).toggle();
            });
            $('#toggleArtists').html($('#toggleArtists').data('state') == 'shown' ? 'Hide Artists' : 'Show Artists');
        });

        $('#toggleMixes').click(function () {
            $('li.mix').each(function () {
                $(this).toggle();
            });
            $('#toggleMixes').html($('#toggleMixes').data('state') == 'shown' ? 'Hide Mixes' : 'Show Mixes');
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <button id="showAll">Show All</button>
    <button id="toggleBlog">Hide Blogs</button>
    <button id="toggleArtists">Hide Artists</button>
    <button id="toggleMixes">Hide Mixes</button>

    <ul>
        <li class="blog">Blog 1</li>
        <li class="blog">Blog 2</li>
        <li class="artist">Artist 1</li>
        <li class="mix">MIX 1</li>
        <li class="blog">BLOG 3</li>
        <li class="artist">Artist 2</li>
    </ul>
```

Here, We handle toggle the hide/show state of the elements based on the html inside button

And, once the `show all` button is clicked, all elements are shown

Comment: hey @sarfraaz-talat I used the javascript code - works great! one more question - whenever ARTISTS or MIX or BLOGS button are clicked, is it possible to to change the text on SHOW ALL to "NOT ALL"?

so when you open the site it says SHOW ALL, but the moment any of the other buttons is clicked SHOW ALL turns into NOT ALL. if two other buttons are clicked it's still NOT ALL and it will only return to SHOW ALL when you either unclick the clicked ARTISTS/BLOGS/MIX buttons OR simply click back NOT ALL and it will go to SHOW ALL... hope I explained myself clearly, sorry :)

Comment: I have updated the javascript code for the change you suggested

Comment: thank you! would you be so kind to explain to me how this line works `'Hide Blogs' ? 'Show Blogs' : 'Hide Blogs';`

Comment: I mean - why are there two "Hide Blogs"? what does the ? and : symbols mean?

Comment: That's a turnary operator, so I am matching current html with 'Hide Blogs', if its true, meaning that current html is `hide Blogs` then we'll make it `Show blogs`, otherwise keep it `Hide blogs`